# Good way to bind user data to menu items in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

I have a `UserData` class instance containing a user's settings and other information. Since it has settings for different parts of the application, it should be easily accessible anywhere. For this reason it's a static property on the `App` class.

I need a menu where some checkable items are two-way bound to some of the (`Boolean`, obviously) settings so that the menu item always shows if the setting is on/off and can be used to toggle it.

Since the `UserData` instance is a static property, it doesn't natively work with two-way binding.

What would be the best way to solve this situation? Is there a way that doesn't require instantiating throwaway objects or manually creating a dependency property for each and every setting individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't bind directly to the static property itself, but you can use the value of a static property as a binding source and then bind to its properties just as you would any other object instance. There are a few variations of what your Binding will look like but if you want to do a bunch of properties on the same object you can use the static object as a DataContext (which is One-Way) and then normal bindings on the MenuItems:

```
<Menu DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Static App.UserData}}">
    <MenuItem Header="1" IsChecked="{Binding SomeUserProperty}"/>
    <MenuItem Header="2" IsChecked="{Binding Property2}"/>
</Menu>
```

Comment: This is one of the things I tried, and it's not working (breakpoints on the bound properties' getter and setter are not triggered by the menu clicking, and the menu item is never checked even if the initial value is true). I'll try to create a clean test app when I have the time, but I really don't see what could be interfering with it.

Comment: Are you getting binding errors in your output window? If the syntax on the static binding isn't quite right you would see something there but nothing happening in the UI.

Comment: There was no error until I added `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` which revealed the problem — DataContext was being set before `UserData` was actually instantiated/loaded (and because of it being a static property there is no `NotifyPropertyChanged` involved when it updates). I moved it to code-behind & ensured it was called at the appropriate time, and it works now. Thanks.